# Link works on localhost but not heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Weird, everything's been working fine in my application on heroku until today. I must have changed something. I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions. None of the links going to the question index work (but everything works fine running on localhost). The heroku db has been migrated and the urls are going to the right place. Here is the heroku log error I'm getting:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Question with id=4)
```

and the pages says:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

Here are what the links look like:

```
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(comment) %>
```

and here's questions#index:

```
def index
  @comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
  @questions = @comment.questions
  @question = Question.find params[:comment_id]
end
```

Here are the routes:

```
 resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
  end
 end

 resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
 end
 end
```

I think the problem is that it's looking for the question id even though it's the questions index page. The links aren't working from the posts pages or the comments pages. If you need me to post more files let me know in the comments.

Comment: Which ruby versions you have on localhost vs. heroku? Try running this command :`heroku run "ruby -v"`.

Comment: ruby 2.0.0 on heroku and 1.9.3 on localhost. That might be the issue. Do you know how i would go about updating ruby?

Comment: The reason I asked was because in Ruby 1.9.3 and below, `nil.id` would return 4, whereas in Ruby 2.0.0 `nil.id` returns an error. Try adding `ruby "2.0.0"` to the top of your Gemfile.

Comment: Would i not want 2.0.0?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant to write. I fixed the comment.

Comment: Hmm it says Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0.

Comment: Have a look at the [heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) for ruby versions.

Comment: No i don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong in your `questions#index`:

```
@question = Question.find params[:comment_id]
```

You're trying to find a question based on the Comment ID, which probably isn't what you intended. The problem is, there's no other ID that you could use either.

If you run `rake routes` you can see a list of all the routes generated by your `config/routes.rb` file. You should see a route like this:

```
comment_questions GET comments/:comment_id/questions questions#index
```

This means that when someone visits a url like `/comments/4/questions` (which can be generated with the helper `comment_questions_path`) they will call the `index` method of `QuestionsController`, and `params[:comment_id]` will equal 4. Your code is trying to look up the Comment with ID 4 **and** the Question with ID 4 - but there isn't a question with ID 4 in your database, so the app crashes.

What is `@question` supposed to refer to anyway? The questions index page should generally be used to list ALL The questions for a particular comment, rather than any specific one of them.

---

PS you don't need to include the inner `do ... end` in your routes:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
  end
end
```

can just be

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `params[:comment_id]` as the `question_id`

Comment: so change to params[:id]?

Comment: Show the ```routes``` and the relationship between the models.

Comment: Added the routes to the question. The relationship is comments has_many questions and question belongs_to comment.

Comment: params[:id] will be `nil` for the routes you've given. See my answer.